# A function to compare sets; help improving efficiency

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am attempting to write a function which compares two lists to see if they represent the same set.  That is `'(a b c d d)` and `'(d c b a d)` represent the same set.  The elements can be in any order.

This is what I have, which works:

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
  (cond
    ((null list1) (null list2))
    ((eq list2 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)) nil)
    (t (samesetP (cdr list1) (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1))))))
```

The reason I do not like this is that `(remove (car list1) list2 :count 1))` is being computed twice - once to test if the `remove` operation truly removed anything, and once to recursively test the rest of the list(s) sans that element.

Can anyone suggest a way to improve this without using a different algorithm?

Comment: You should use hashtables, this will bring down the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

Comment: I am confused.  You're using a horrible algorithm, and want improvements as long as they don't involve fixing the bad algorithm.  Why?  As @leppie said, use hash tables.  Or else sort both lists, and walk them in parallel.  The better algorithm will make much more of a difference than the micro-optimization you are concerned with.

Comment: Chill out guys, we aren't allowed to use hash tables.  It's part of a homework problem.  If you can think of a more efficient algorithm that can be contained within about 10 lines of code, please enlighten me.

Comment: Don't use trailing parentheses on their own line. Lisp is not C or Java.

Comment: In support of Rainer's comment - see http://mumble.net/~campbell/scheme/style.txt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
    (cond
        ((null list1) (null list2))
        ((eq list2 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)) nil)
        (t (samesetP (cdr list1) (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1))))
    )
)
```

First let's format it correctly:

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
  (cond ((null list1) (null list2))
        ((eq list2 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)) nil)
        (t (samesetP (cdr list1) (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)))))
```

If you use a form twice and you want to change that, then you need to store a value. LET is the construct for that. If it doesn't fit into one COND, then you need a second one.

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
  (cond ((null list1) (null list2))
        (t (let ((list3 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)))
             (cond ((eq list2 list3) nil)
                   (t (samesetP (cdr list1) list3)))))))
```

Now, EQ can't be used to compare lists. Use EQUAL.

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
  (cond ((null list1) (null list2))
        (t (let ((list3 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)))
             (cond ((equal list2 list3) nil)
                   (t (samesetP (cdr list1) list3)))))))
```

COND is overkill here, use IF:

```
(defun samesetp (list1 list2)
  (if (null list1)
      (null list2)
    (let ((list3 (remove (car list1) list2 :count 1)))
      (if (equal list2 list3)
          nil
        (samesetP (cdr list1) list3)))))
```

Now, you only need to make the function do what was asked in the homework. But it is your homework anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I see LET is what might really help here.

Comment: You should mark Rainer's answer as accepted if this is what helped you. I'll add that it's a good answer at that, so +1.

Comment: Yes, I did mark it.  Thanks Rainer I really do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not allowed to use built-in functions for solving the problem, but just to note there is one:

```
(set-difference list1 list2)
```

Comment: ITYM `set-exclusive-or`. For `set-difference`, the order of arguments matters.