# How can I make equivalence function in Common Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I know that it is possible to check if 2 lists have the same sets with using "EQUAL" function in Common Lisp.

> (equal '(a b c) '(a b c)) => T
>
> (equal '(a b c) '(b c a)) => T
>
> (equal '(a b c) '(d e f)) => NIL

But you know, it is impossible if the two lists have the same sets if the sets are arranged in different orders.

I guess that it may be possible to make the function which can predicate that tests whether two sets contain the same elements even if they are arranged in different orders with using 'remove' function and recursion. But, I can't concrete my idea to make this function exactly.

How can I realize the idea?

Comment: Also add `(equal '(a b c) '(b c a)) => T` to your example

Comment: Thanks! But, My Allegro CL program doesn't express T when I input them!

Comment: Ah, I was telling you to add that so that other people know that that is one of the requirements

Comment: Please update your post with your attempt.

Comment: Okay! I did that!

Comment: If you want to use built-in CL facilities, you can use `set-exclusive-or` like this: `(defun sets-equivalent (set-a set-b) (not (set-exclusive-or set-a set-b)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that does exactly this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930493/a-function-to-compare-sets-help-improving-efficiency). The OP of that question has a working solution, and the accepted answer is a better solution.

What I will do is try to explain the logic.

Let's step through this problem first. You're given 2 lists, `list1` and `list2`.

1. If `list1` is null, then return true if `list2` is also null. ( You don't need to check the opposite of this, that gets taken care of in step 2 )
2. Else (`list` is not null/empty): We have to somehow, as you suggested, remove an element that is in both sets. This can be achieved by *letting* `list3` be a list such that it is `list2` with the first item in `list1` removed.

   i. If nothing is removed, i.e, then `list2` and `list3` are equal (you can use normal `equal` here), and so the function returns false, because it finds an element in `list1` that is not in `list2`

   ii. If something is removed then call our function again on the (rest of `list1`) and `list3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in CL facilities, you can use [`set-exclusive-or`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_ex.htm) like this:

```
(defun sets-equivalent (set-a set-b)
  (not (set-exclusive-or set-a set-b)))
```

Per CLHS:

> set-exclusive-or returns a list of elements that appear in exactly one of list-1 and list-2.

So if returned list is empty, it means sets are equivalent.